# what does stack mean in oops message?

Tags: oop, kernel

I'm learning Linux Device Driver

There is a chapter about OOPS Message， and there is a stack part in this message

I don't under stand the numbers in the stack area; and I googled, didn't find answer about this;

Can anybody help to explain it?

```
EIP: 0010:[<00000000>]
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffffff
 printing eip:
ffffffff
Oops: 0000 [#5]
SMP
CPU: 0
EIP: 0060:[<ffffffff>] Not tainted
EFLAGS: 00010296 (2.6.6)
EIP is at 0xffffffff
eax: 0000000c ebx: ffffffff ecx: 00000000 edx: bfffda7c
esi: cf434f00 edi: ffffffff ebp: 00002000 esp: c27fff78
ds: 007b es: 007b ss: 0068
Process head (pid: 2331, threadinfo=c27fe000 task=c3226150)
Stack: ffffffff bfffda70 00002000 cf434f20 00000001 00000286 cf434f00 fffffff7
 bfffda70 c27fe000 c0150612 cf434f00 bfffda70 00002000 cf434f20 00000000
 00000003 00002000 c0103f8f 00000003 bfffda70 00002000 00002000 bfffda70
Call Trace:
 [<c0150612>] sys_read+0x42/0x70
 [<c0103f8f>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
Code: Bad EIP value.
```

Comment: Unders `Stack:` you see the content of the first bytes of memory, started at the stack pointer (`esp` in your case). Every number represents several bytes at once (on x86 - 4 bytes).

Comment: I see, the content of ESP! thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tsyvarev,
He said the content After Stack: is the content that the ESP points to

That should be stack frame, By looking them, especially address pattern, we can get clue where the oops happens when EIP is invalid.